# confused about android example code

Tags: android

I'm looking over some code on the android developer's site and have a quick question about the example show here - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

In particular, I'm looking at this piece of code -

```
public static class DetailsActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
            == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // If the screen is now in landscape mode, we can show the
        // dialog in-line with the list so we don't need this activity.
        finish();
        return;
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
        DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
        details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
    }
}
```

What is the point of the second if statement -

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
```

I can't find any situation where this if statement wouldn't be true.  I've tested this code by adding an else statement and setting a breakpoint in it.  I could not get to that breakpoint no matter I tried.  So why even bother with an if statement?  Why not leave it out all together?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. check this

Comment: I am aware of what instance states are used for, my question is why would the code I listed ever have a non-null instance state?  The if statement will always evaluate to true in the example given.

Comment: if you are aware you would know why the code was used. do read the docs full.

Comment: I've have read it, the code in question will always evaluate to true.  There is no way for the instance state in the example to ever be non-null.

Answer (score 1):

There are situations in which your Activity is stopped by the Android operating system. In those cases, you get a chance to save the state of your Activity by a call to [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle). If after this, your Activity is started again, it'll be passed the `Bundle` you created so that you can restore the state properly.

Comment: I am aware of what instance states are used for, my question is why would the code I listed ever have a non-null instance state? The if statement will always evaluate to true in the example given.

Comment: I was assuming that you have only pasted the `onCreate` method of the Activity. If the code you posted is the entire Activity, then the if statement will always evaluate to `true`. It is good practice to include it there though so that in case someone uses the code as a starting point, they are aware of the case where the value may not be null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look at the complete example code. With this part it makes sense.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}
```

If you start your Activity the first time the Bundle savedInstanceState will be null and the body of the if statement will be executed. If onSaveInstanceState is called, because you navigated away from the Activity, the Bundle isn't null anymore and the if body will be not executed.

Comment: The code you reference is for a different fragment/activity - (The TitlesFragment which is containted in the MainActivity).  The code I listed is for the DetailsActivity.

Answer (score 0):

If your app was paused/killed, etc and you saved state by `onSaveInstanceState` then 
savedInstanceState will contain the state of your app that you saved. Otherwise it will be null.

Comment: I am aware of what instance states are used for, my question is why would the code I listed ever have a non-null instance state? The if statement will always evaluate to true in the example given.

Comment: @user2700452 No it won't.  If Android kills and then recreates the Activity, then the instance state saved in onSaveInstanceState will be passed in.

Comment: But there isn't an instance State - the entire activity is listed in my example. There isn't anything to save.  It will always be null.

Comment: This activity may not save any of its state but the Activity superclass certainly does. Off the top of my head I know it saves information about any Fragments it contains.

Comment: Even if that were the case, why would you want to prevent the code in the if statement from running?  The example is a simple two activity app, the first being a list of titles that when one is selected launch the second activity with details for that title.  In what circumstance would you want to prevent the second activity from loading the correct details?  If the if statement ever evaluated to false (which it won't, I've tried) - the second activity would still show the details from the previously selected title, not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was added to the example for future expansion on this code.  While it has absolutely no functionality as it stands right now, if this activity were to launch another activity and get killed while the new activity had focus, this code would rebuild the activity when the user hits the back button, rather than rebuilding from scratch.